# Two properties of same type mapping to a single table which has a column to distinguish the target property

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have two tables:

```
parents
  id

childs
  parent_id
  child_number
```

and two corresponding entity-types where i want the type Parent to have two navigation properties linking to the first and second child:

```
class Parent
  property Child1 : Child
  property Child2 : Child
```

I am searching for something along the lines of

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
  .Map(f => f.Child1, m => m.Requires("child_number").HasValue(0))
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
  .Map(f => f.Child2, m => m.Requires("child_number").HasValue(1))
```

Is this possible without having two destinct, derived types `Child1 : Child` and `Child2 : Child`?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm sure it's possible to have a dynamic `ChildN` type/property, I would go with a different approach. So that's what I'm going to suggest.

I think in your situation it would make more sense to have a `Parent` reference a collection of children, rather than explicitly having properties for `Child1`,`Child2`,...,`ChildN`.

I would advocate that this not only solves your problem (or at least fulfills your needs) but would allow for potential future extension. If you did this, you'd end up handling selection of 1st,2nd,...,nth child with a separate piece of logic.

Instead you end up with two POCOs for Parent and Child

```
public class Parent()
{
    public Parent() { Children = new HashSet<Child>(); }
    [Required]
    public int Id {get;set}|

    //Collection of Child objects as navigation property
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children{get;set;}
}


public class Child()
{
    [Required]
    public int ParentId {get;set}
    [Required]
    public int ChildNumber{get;set}

    //Collection of Child objects as navigation property
    public virtual Parent Parent {get; set;}
}
```

Fluent API mapping. This Fluent API code could also include the [Required] information as `Property`s with `IsRequired()`, but it was easier for me to stick it in the model definition, and it would've crowded the more important mapping information of the Fluent API.

```
mBuilder.Entity<Parent>().HasKey(p=>p.Id);

mBuilder.Entity<Parent>().HasMany(p=>p.Children)
    .WithRequired(c=>c.Parent)
    .HasForeignKey(c=>c.ParentId);

mBuilder.Entity<Child>
    .HasKey(c=> new {c.ParentId, c.ChildNumber});
```

One possible approach for retrieving the Nth Child

```
GetNthChild(parent, N)
{
    return parent.Children.Where(c => c.ChildNumber ==N);
}
```

Or you could even define your own Children class that implements an Indexer to get the Nth child; but how you decide to go about getting the Nth child is up to you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. This is very much like my current implementation. Yet I wanted to avoid any `.Where(c => c.ChildNumber == n)` queries and have my Properties populated with the SQL-query. Extensibility is no concern (maybe my example using Parent and Child was a bad idea - a class Bike with two properties FrontWeel and BackWeel would have been more appropriate)

Comment: Understandable, I agree that it would feel nice to avoid writing LINQ like that. That said, even with navigation properties (or something more dynamic like you wanted), EF still makes a SQL call to get `Parent.Child`, that's part of Lazy Loading used in EF. 

If you want to "avoid" SQL calls to get related object, you could disable lazy loading for the Nav Prop, but in that case EF loads `Child` with a SQL call whenever you get load a `Parent`, the only difference is when you want to ask EF to get the data from the database. Regardless of using a LINQ query, EF is always using SQL to get stuff